# How is BLS secure against adaptive selection message attacks when the message is known?

Tags: bls-signature

Maybe the below question is similar to what I was thinking, but I don't understand:
[Is BLS signature scheme strongly unforgeable?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/56288/is-bls-signature-scheme-strongly-unforgeable)

Below is the attack method I was thinking of. If know m, can't create a new signature from it?

- sk is secret key
- pk is public key
- m is message
- S is signature
- e(P, Q) : bilinear pairing

Sign :
$$
pk=sk \cdot P\\
S=sk \cdot m \cdot Q\\
$$

Verify:
$$
e(P, S) = e(P, sk \cdot m \cdot Q) == e(pk, m \cdot Q) = e(sk \cdot P, m \cdot Q)\\
== e(P, Q)^{sk \cdot m}
$$

Evil:
$$
S' = \frac{1}{m} \cdot m' \cdot S = m' \cdot sk\cdot Q
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how the [Boneh-Lynn-Schacham scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLS_digital_signature) works. Instead, in your notation, the point $S$ is calculated by hashing a message $m$ to a point  on the curve $H(m)$ (in a publicly known and verifiable way such as [this draft RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-irtf-cfrg-hash-to-curve/)) and then multiplying by $sk$, thus:
$$S=sk\cdot H(m).$$
Verification then checks that
$$e(S,P)=e(H(m),pk).$$

Unless there is a a spectacularly bad choice of $H$, there should be no known scalar relationship between $H(m)$ and $H(m')$. Your attack needs $H(m')=\frac{m'}mH(m)$ which will not be true in general.

Comment: thank you! https://coingeek.com/bls-signatures-on-bitcoin-pairing-based-cryptography-part-2/ also worked for me. In short, is it correct to use points close to m in the curve group instead of using the generator point? And can define the found point as m'G, but my attack is impossible because it is difficult to find m' from the point?

Comment: The notation and terminology is getting a little muddled, but I think that is correct.